# Fetch Max Value

Tags: sql

```
   TABLE Laptop_Shift_Departments 

   id     Laptop_ID  Curr_department    Pre_Department
    -----|----------|-----------------|----------------
    9        71            4                 3
    10       68            4                 3
    11       71            5                 4
    12       68            5                 4
```

User only search PO Number and against this PO_Num there are 2 laptops (Laptop_ID)

Above is my table now i want to get MAX value Against this laptop_ID ID

I have tried this:

```
    SELECT LD.ID AS  Laptop_ID,ld.GulfITBarcode,po.ID as PO_ID,PO.PO_Number as PO_Number,D.Department,
    D.ID as Crr_DepID1,d2.Department,D2.ID as Pre_DepID2  
    FROM PO_PURCHASEORDER PO
        INNER JOIN PO_Laptop_Master LM
        ON LM.PO_ID = PO.ID
        INNER JOIN PO_LaptopDetail LD
        ON LD.LapTop_Master_ID = LM.ID
        INNER JOIN Laptop_Shift_Departments DP
        ON DP.Laptop_Detail_ID = LD.ID
        inner join Laptop_Departments d
        on d.ID = DP.Current_Dep_ID
        inner join Laptop_Departments d2
        on d2.ID = DP.Previous_Dep_ID
        WHERE PO_NUMBER = '5258'
        AND
        LD.ID IN (select Max(cSh.id) from Laptop_Shift_Departments cSh)
```

But it is not working

MY output should be like this:

```
id     Laptop_ID  Curr_department    Pre_Department
-----|----------|-----------------|----------------
11       71            5                 4
12       68            5                 4
```

Comment: Your select list doesn't match the result set columns...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the 'Group By' function at the end of the fields you want to group by and the 'Max' function in the Select on the columns you want the 'Max' (or 'Min' or 'Avg').  Should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
     LD.ID AS  Laptop_ID
    ,ld.GulfITBarcode
    ,po.ID as PO_ID
    ,PO.PO_Number as PO_Number
    ,D.Department
    ,MAX(D.ID) as Crr_DepID1
    ,d2.Department
    ,MAX(D2.ID) as Pre_DepID2  
FROM PO_PURCHASEORDER PO
    INNER JOIN PO_Laptop_Master LM
        ON LM.PO_ID = PO.ID
    INNER JOIN PO_LaptopDetail LD
        ON LD.LapTop_Master_ID = LM.ID
    INNER JOIN Laptop_Shift_Departments DP
        ON DP.Laptop_Detail_ID = LD.ID
    inner join Laptop_Departments d
        on d.ID = DP.Current_Dep_ID
    inner join Laptop_Departments d2
        on d2.ID = DP.Previous_Dep_ID
WHERE PO_NUMBER = '5258'
    AND LD.ID IN (select Max(cSh.id) from Laptop_Shift_Departments cSh)
    AND DP.Current_Dep_ID = 5
GROUP BY
     LD.ID 
    ,ld.GulfITBarcode
    ,po.ID 
    ,PO.PO_Number 
    ,D.Department
    ,d2.Department
```

(Having not seen the table structure I'm not sure as to the rest of the query.  Hope this helps.)